# ExperimentalWarning when run the npm install

Tags: reactjs, node-modules

```
npm install
(node:17132) ExperimentalWarning: The fs.promises API is experimental

up to date, audited 1 package in 10s
```

I downloaded the Github project and opened it, I tried to install the node modules for it, I could not install the node modules.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade your nodejs version like this: npm install npm@latest -g

Comment: It doesn't work.                                                                                                                          npm install npm@latest -g
(node:3556) ExperimentalWarning: The fs.promises API is experimental

removed 218 packages, changed 3 packages, and audited 37 packages in 51s

Comment: Can you show your code in codepen or codesandbox?